# Are the submarine cables used only for internet?

Tags: internet, cable

We can see that almost all of the servers are interconnected between each others using submarine cables which ends in a complete hierarchy but question is are those internet connected cables are used only for connecting internet servers between each others ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you define as the "Internet", If by the "Internet" you mean the large mesh of publically routable IP space then no. These cables can also be used to provide direct private optical waves between two endpoints, similar to a very long point-to-point Dark Fibre.

When these wavelengths are sold to providers it is then up to the provider to determine how they wish to use this service. If they want to run their International IP backhaul over it then so be it. From the Cable manufacturers point of view, they're purely selling a Layer 1 service.

Comment: so they are basically used only for TCP/IP connections ? am i right ?

Comment: @Taher, Nope, if I wanted to run just point-to-point layer 2 service then I could.

Comment: yeah i understand but the final goal is to be able to use the TCP/IP connections ? i mean providers will not use them for phone telecommunications or other goal ?

Comment: Telephone, fax, video conferencing, text messaging, it doesn't really matter as they can all be translated to some protocol that flows on top of IP. A lot of it would be UDP actually. But as people have said before, you rent a specific wavelength of light in a strand of fibre, then what you do with that wavelength is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

No  this cable can carry different types of traffic other than internet traffic . Submarines cables are just physical connectivity from and to connecting two geographical locations . Further to i this cable bandwidth can be utilised for internet and point to point links for private leased lines connectivity this can be achieved  by creating vlans isolating traffic that passes through this Submarine cable using Vlans